How to import Databricks Catalog table into Data Services?
We have received a requirement to extract the data from Databrics Catalog table data into MSSQL. As part of development we have created a ODBC connection for Databrics using Simba Spark Drivers and connection test is successful. However, when we are trying to import the table with appropriate schema encountering the Table/View not exists wherein the table is exists in the Databrics catalog.
The error says

select * from .." results error, we assume the database name is not concatenated in the query from Data services,

I am not sure whether the assumption is right or wrong also.

You have not defined what catalog you need to access therefore it cant find you schema/tables.
The catalog can be set under the registry.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Simba\Simba Spark ODBC Driver\Driver\Catalog

This answer could be improved with a link to a reference source that explains what type of value you need to put at that registry location.
